# Add a jar file to depedencies in a Maven in NetBeans

Tags: java, windows, maven, netbeans, repository

I have a local just and I want to add it to dependencies of a Maven.

I try to things work according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22300875/6326346)

My file is somewhere locally so I use this in the pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>opt</groupId>
    <artifactId>Copt</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <systemPath>$C:\Users\annia\files\example.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

What is the right way to right the systemPath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, Maven downloads all dependencies automatically from the remote repository (a repository, which has almost all libraries). But sometimes, due to some issues, the remote repositories cannot have jar files and in this case, you should download jar file manually and install this jar file into your local maven repository(the maven repository in your local computer) manually.

If i understood correctly, you want to add a custom jar file to your local maven repository. The [link](https://softwarecave.org/2014/06/14/adding-external-jars-into-maven-project/) explains how you should do it. I have learnt also from here. If it will not help, [this](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-include-library-manully-into-maven-local-repository/) or [this](http://blog.valdaris.com/post/custom-jar/) links may help.

Comment: Did this answer help you ?